# Upper bound for a conditional variance (and expectation)

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, polynomials, convex-analysis, conditional-probability

Let $V(x,y)\in C^\infty$ be a uniformly convex function with polynomial growth, i.e. there exist $\alpha>0$, $n\in\mathbb N$, $k>0$ such that
$$Hess V(x,y) \,\geq\, \alpha\, I \quad\textrm{for all }(x,y)\in\mathbb R^{d_1}\times\mathbb R^{d_2}$$
$$V(x,y) \,\leq\, k\,(|x|^{2n}+|y|^{2n}) \quad\textrm{as }|x|^2+|y|^2\to\infty \;.$$

We may assume w.l.o.g. $\int\!\int e^{-V(x,y)} dx\,dy=1$, so that $e^{-V(x,y)}dx\,dy\,$ is a log-concave probability measure.

I am interested in the conditional probabily measure.
In particular I wonder if -maybe under additional assumption on $V$ and its derivatives- we have
$$ \frac{\int |x|^{2p}\,e^{-V(x,y)}\,dx}{\int e^{-V(x,y)} dx}  \,-\,  \left(\frac{\int |x|^{p}\,e^{-V(x,y)}\,dx}{\int e^{-V(x,y)} dx}\right)^2 \,\leq\, h_1\,|y|^{2p} + h_0$$
for any $p \in \mathbb N$ and for suitable constants $h_1,h_0\geq0$ (that depend on $p$ and $V$).

**In other terms:** is the variance of $|x|^{p}$ given $y$ bounded by a polynomial in $|y|$ ?

**Example.** The answer is yes in the case of Gaussian measure. Indeed if $e^{-V(x,y)}dx\,dy\,$ is the Gaussian measure with mean $0$ and positive-definite covariance matrix $A$, then the conditional measure given $y$ turns out to be the Gaussian measure with mean $A_{12}A_{22}^{-1}y$ and covariance matrix $A_{11}-A_{12}A_{22}^{-1}A_{12}^T$. Then a simple change of variable $x\mapsto x+A_{12}A_{22}^{-1}y$ allows to conclude.

**Edit.** After computations in the case of Gaussian measure, and after some simple numerics for a non-Gaussian measure ($2n=4$), I suspect the same inequality could hold true also for expectations. Namely:
$$ \frac{\int |x|^{p}\,e^{-V(x,y)}\,dx}{\int e^{-V(x,y)} dx} \,\leq\, h_1\,|y|^p + h_0$$
for every $p\in\mathbb N$ and for suitable constants $h_0,h_1\geq0$ which depend of $p$ and $V$. Of course this would imply the previous inequality for variances.

**Edit 2.** By continuity of the functions involved, an equivalent formulation of the previous inequality is:
$$ L\equiv \limsup_{|y|\to\infty} \frac{\int |x|^{p}\,e^{-V(x,y)}\,dx}{|y|^p \int e^{-V(x,y)} dx} <\infty \;.$$

**Edit 3.** **Conjecture**: if $V(x,y)$ is a uniformly convex polynomial of degree $2n\geq 2$ and $p\in\mathbb N$, there exists a positive-definite covariance matrix $A$ such that
$$ \frac{\int |x|^{2p} e^{-V(x,y)} dx}{\int e^{-V(x,y)} dx} \,\leq\, \frac{\int |x|^{2p} e^{-G(x,y)} dx}{\int e^{-G(x,y)} dx}$$
where $G(x,y) = \frac{1}{2}\langle A^{-1}(x-x_0,y-y_0) , (x-x_0,y-y_0)\rangle $
and $(x_0,y_0)$ is the unique minimum point of $V$.
Now in the Gaussian case we can perform computations explcitly, finding
$$ \frac{\int |x|^{2p} e^{-G(x,y)} dx}{\int e^{-G(x,y)} dx} \leq h_1\,|y|^{2p} + h_0 $$
for suitable constants $h_0,h_1$. Thus if the conjecture holds true, it would prove the desired bound for conditional moments, at least in the case $V$ is a polynomial.

Comment: Just a few thoughts, in the expression of $L$ the numerator can be easily bounded using the convexity condition for $V$ and Taylor's theorem, giving the bound requested. However the denominator doesn't have a easy upper bound given the assumptions and one has to get a lot smarter- perhaps this is where the asymptotics come into play.

Comment: @DinosaurEgg thanks for your comment. Exactly the numerator would be easy by uniform convexity and taylor expansion. But maybe it could be better to think to the whole ratio together. In the Gaussian case for example the conditional measure turns out to be Gaussian with covariance matrix independent of $y$ (hence no $y$ in the normalization)